# Are there differences between IBM JDK on AIX and on Linux

Tags: java, linux, aix

Our server side application currently supports running on the IBM JDK on Linux. The same application also works fine with Oracle JDK. We are asked to support IBM JDK on AIX as well. Are there any major differences between the two JDKs that should worry us?
We are using the usual open source stack like

- Spring
- Lucene
- Apache Wicket
- Birt
- myBatis
- Custom Classloaders

Comment: Side note: I would recommend you looking around http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/learn/java/index.html ... maybe you find a forum/community there; much better chance of getting a good answer there than here.

Comment: It is very similar.  You should strongly consider adding AIX to the platforms where your automatic tests run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't find any differences at that high layer between the two platforms. That's kind of an important point for Java much less with the same level of JVM from the same vendor.

Comment: Well we encountered some differences on the detail level between Oracle JDK and IBM JDK and I was wondering if such differences would be expected for JDKs of the same vendor on different platforms as well - or if we should not be worried too much.